# not eligible for auto-proxying with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javabeans

see the info

trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'dataSource' of type [class com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

I looked for some questions in this web ,but I can not understand 。
I use  spring bootI mybatis when I combine them it is wrong.

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = "w.p.j.dao")
public class MybatisConfig {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    @Autowired
    private DruidDataSourceEntity druidDataSourceEntity;
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        logger.info("------------druidDataSourceEntity------" + druidDataSourceEntity);
        //加载配置文件属性
        DruidDataSource dataSource = new DruidDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(druidDataSourceEntity.getDriverClassName());
        dataSource.setUsername(druidDataSourceEntity.getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(druidDataSourceEntity.getPassword());
        dataSource.setUrl(druidDataSourceEntity.getUrl());
        dataSource.setMaxActive(druidDataSourceEntity.getMaxActive());
        dataSource.setValidationQuery(druidDataSourceEntity.getValidationQuery());
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(druidDataSourceEntity.isTestOnBorrow());
        dataSource.setTestOnReturn(druidDataSourceEntity.isTestOnReturn());
        dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(druidDataSourceEntity.isTestWhileIdle());
        dataSource.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(druidDataSourceEntity.getTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis());
        dataSource.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(druidDataSourceEntity.getMinEictableIdleTimeMillis());
        dataSource.setPoolPreparedStatements(druidDataSourceEntity.isPoolPreparedStatements());
        dataSource.setMaxOpenPreparedStatements(druidDataSourceEntity.getMaxOpenPreparedStatements());
        try {
            dataSource.setFilters(druidDataSourceEntity.getFilters());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    public Resource[] getResource(String basePackage, String pattern) throws IOException {
        String packageSearchPath = ResourcePatternResolver.CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX
                + ClassUtils.convertClassNameToResourcePath(new StandardEnvironment()
                .resolveRequiredPlaceholders(basePackage)) + "/" + pattern;
        Resource[] resources = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources(packageSearchPath);
        return resources;
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        logger.info("------> sqlSessionFactory");
        final SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sqlSessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sqlSessionFactory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("mybatis-config.xml"));
        sqlSessionFactory.setFailFast(true);
        sqlSessionFactory.setMapperLocations(getResource("mapper", "**/*.xml"));
        //配置插件
        return sqlSessionFactory.getObject();
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        logger.info("> transactionManager");
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")//这个注解蛮重要的，保证线程安全
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate() {

        try {
            logger.info("SqlSessionTemplate---");
            return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.info("---sqlSesson----","空");
        return null;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        logger.info("jdbc.settings={}", druidDataSourceEntity);
        logger.info("sqlSession",sqlSessionTemplate());

    }
}
```

when my config is XMl,it will be ok with spring mvc .
maybe caused by      but I don't know how can I do in spring boot if you have a good idea or you have a better solution or you can give me a  demo  ，please tell me .I really appreciate your help first

Comment: Remove the `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: Thank you anyway but it can not work still